# Pre-Processor Concatenation Failing

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, qemu

I am doing some work in QEMU v2.9.0 (The latest tagged version) and in the `{QEMU_Root}/include/qemu/bswap.h` file they are generating some functions based on endianess.

The code is shown below:

```
#define CPU_CONVERT(endian, size, type)\
static inline type endian ## size ## _to_cpu(type v)\
{\
    return glue(endian, _bswap)(v, size);\
}\
\
static inline type cpu_to_ ## endian ## size(type v)\
{\
    return glue(endian, _bswap)(v, size);\
}\
\
static inline void endian ## size ## _to_cpus(type *p)\
{\
    glue(endian, _bswaps)(p, size);\
}\
\
static inline void cpu_to_ ## endian ## size ## s(type *p)\
{\
    glue(endian, _bswaps)(p, size);\
}\

CPU_CONVERT(be, 16, uint16_t)
CPU_CONVERT(be, 32, uint32_t)
CPU_CONVERT(be, 64, uint64_t)

CPU_CONVERT(le, 16, uint16_t)
CPU_CONVERT(le, 32, uint32_t)
CPU_CONVERT(le, 64, uint64_t)
```

I don't need to touch this code, but for some reason it is not compiling properly. I keep getting the error:

```
/home/xubuntu/Development/QEMU/Source/v2.9.0/include/qemu/bswap.h:162:13: error: ‘be’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 CPU_CONVERT(be, 16, uint16_t)
             ^
/home/xubuntu/Development/QEMU/Source/v2.9.0/include/qemu/bswap.h:144:17: note: in definition of macro ‘CPU_CONVERT’
     return glue(endian, _bswap)(v, size);\
                 ^
/home/xubuntu/Development/QEMU/Source/v2.9.0/include/qemu/bswap.h:162:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 CPU_CONVERT(be, 16, uint16_t)
             ^
/home/xubuntu/Development/QEMU/Source/v2.9.0/include/qemu/bswap.h:144:17: note: in definition of macro ‘CPU_CONVERT’
     return glue(endian, _bswap)(v, size);\
```

The same error shows up for `"le"`. Any ideas what might cause something like this to happen?

**EDIT:**

In the comments there was some confusion about what the `glue` function call actually is. It is also a pre-processor macro defined in `{QEMU_Root}/include/qemu/compiler.h`

```
#define xglue(x, y) x ## y
#define glue(x, y) xglue(x, y)
```

Comment: Please read, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. You are not a new member !

Comment: "*`‘be’ undeclared`*" well .. how and where are `be` and `le` defined?

Comment: I never knew it was required to wrap in sentence code. I've done it many times and no one has ever corrected me. The code block fix was a copy/paste error on my part. I read the link you posted and will try to utilize it in my questions moving forward. Thanks

Comment: @alk So again, this is QEMU code, not mine. I can do a search, but my understanding is "be"/"le" are not variables, but tokens to be operated on by the pre-processor. They should not have to be defined as they will become parts of function names after the pre-processor acts on them.

Comment: "*... they will become parts of function names*" yes, correct. But *additionally* they are passed to the `glue()` "function calls" (or what ever this is, as you do not show this to us)  as 1st parameter. The compiler's error message notify on this.

Comment: I can double check, but I'm fairly certain that `glue()` is also a pre-processor macro. It is found in `{QEMU_Root}/include/qemu/compiler.h`. I have updated the question to show this.

Comment: Can you compile the problem module using the option `-E` to capture the preprocessor output and show what the preprocessor is generating for the `CPU_CONVERT(be, 16, uint16_t)` line?  (just post the results for that one line).

Comment: I'll see if I can get it to do that.

Comment: Are you certain that the header defining `glue` has been #included?

Comment: E.g., something in your library might just decide to `#define _bswap` to track something.  Now `_bswap` is an object like macro that expands to nothing, and thus if `endian` is `be`, then `glue(endian,_bswap)` becomes `be` rather than the intended `be_bswap`.

Comment: (delete/correct of previous comment): You really should change `glue(endian,_bswap)` and variants to something like `glue(glue(endian,_),bswap)`. This might be your problem but it's impossible to tell without your environment; but identifiers beginning with an underscore are reserved by your implementation and, by using such identifiers in an indirect-paste (aka glue macro), you're allowing such things to fiddle with what you're doing

Comment: @HWalters: The implementation can only define macros starting with two underscores or an underscore followed by a capital letter. `_bswap` might be an "identifier with file scope", but not a macro. So it's ok in this context. (In theory). (See section 7.1.3, also 6.10.8/2)

Comment: I was working on getting the pre-processor output via the -E option in the make file, but didn't have much luck going down that route. I'll check the includes to ensure compiler.h is indeed included.

Comment: @rici You hit the nail on the head. An older version of QEMU I was used to had the file `include/qemu/compiler.h` included in the files I included for my project. The newest version of QEMU (2.9.0 at the time of writing) has imports re-organized in a way that required me to include something that has `include/qemu/compiler.h` in it.

Comment: So the problem is solved now?

Comment: Yes. The problem was `glue` being treated as a function and not a pre-processor macro. Once the proper header file with the `glue` definition was included, it compiled.

Comment: FYI, every source file in QEMU should have access to the definitions in compiler.h, because the rule is that every .c file should #include "qemu/osdep.h" as the first #include it does, and osdep.h includes compiler.h. (And so no .c file should directly include compiler.h.)

Comment: Yes that is the header I ended up including. Is that rule in documentation somewhere? I am trying to do things the proper QEMU way, but I have a hard time finding documentation on implementing new boards/machines.